# How to use DispatchGroup to update UI only after for-in loop has completed

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, for-in-loop, dispatchgroup

When a user taps a button, that triggers a lengthy function consisting of an API call and calculations.

```
@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        
        var itemIndex = 0
        let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
        
        for name in (entireRecipe?.extendedIngredients!)! {
            
            dispatchGroup.enter()
            
            CalculatorService().calculate() { item   in
                self.arrayItem.append(item)
                self.totalItems = self.arrayItems.reduce(0, +)
            }
            itemIndex = itemIndex + 1
        }
        dispatchGroup.leave()
        
        dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("DispatchGroup Notified")
            self.itemLabel.text = "\(self.totalItems)"
        }
    }
```

My rationale on the above is that:

1. dispatchGroup is entered when the for-in loop starts
2. dispatchGroup is left after the for-in loop has iterated through the entire array
3. dispatchGroup is only then notified, and the UI label is updated

However, it looks like `dispatchGroup.notify` is not being run when intended, and so the UI label is not being updated after the for-in loop is complete.

Is there anything missing from my `dispatchGroup` code? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `leave` line must be **inside** the closure

```
for name in (entireRecipe?.extendedIngredients!)! {
    
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    
    CalculatorService().calculate() { item   in
        self.arrayItem.append(item)
        self.totalItems = self.arrayItems.reduce(0, +)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
    itemIndex = itemIndex + 1
}
```

Comment: Hi @vadian. Thank you for chiming in, but unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: Then there  is something wrong with the context. The usual procedure is to call `enter` inside the loop **before** calling the asynchronous task and to call `leave` in the completion handler.

Comment: Is there something I need to do in the task itself to make sure it's asynchronous?

Comment: I have no idea what the task does.

Comment: It turns out it was just a silly error in my code. In combination with your answer, placing ` itemIndex = itemIndex + 1` in the completion handler of my function resolved everything. Thank you so much!